# TryValidateProperty always returns true in Test library

Tags: unit-testing, validation, asp.net-core

I have a class defined in a class library like so:

**Classlib1 - Client**

```
public class client{
   [Required]
   public string Firstname {get; set;}
   ...
   [RegularExpression(@"^(?:\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|)$")]
   public string SocialSecurityNumber {get; set;}
}
```

I also have a Test library where I want to ensure that my RegularExpression Attribute Validation is working.

**Testlib**

```
[TestMethod]
public void ThrowAnErrorOnSSNWithTooManyDigits(){
    var client = new Client(){
       Firstname = "Mickey",
       ...
       SocialSecurityNumber = "1234567890123"
    };
    var vResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var context = new ValidationContext(client){MemberName = "SocialSecurityNumber"};
    var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(client.SocialSecurityNumber, context, vResults);

    Assert.IsFalse(result)
}
```

However, my Assertion always fails because result always equals true.  I tried changing my validator to validate a required firstname instead of SocialSecurityNumber thinking that my RegEx wasn't quite right -- however, that returns true as well -- even if I set Firstname = ""

What do I need to do to get the Validator working in my Test classlib?

Comment: Your code works fine for me...

Comment: Do you have your classes in the same project or in different projects?

Comment: In different projects

Comment: Did you set this up in .net core?  Just trying to narrow down why yours would work and mine would not.

Comment: yes, both projects are .net core 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, In combing through my project once again, I realized that the Test project that I added was actually targeting .Net4.6 while the rest of my projects are all targeting .Net Core 2.0.

I added a new .NetCore Test project and copied all my tests in there and everything worked as expected.